# I have a Cisco 2921, CIS-3G-ANTM1919D (3G Antenna) is attached to it. Please confirm if this is optimum

Tags: cisco, router, wireless, cisco-ios

```
psea399#show Cellular 0/1/0 radio history all

psea399   03:51:51 PM Thursday Mar 17 2016 UTC



      111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  140
  130
  120
  110 ************************************************************
  100 ************************************************************
   90 ************************************************************
   80 ************************************************************
   70 ************************************************************
   60 ************************************************************
   50 ************************************************************
   40 ************************************************************
   30 ************************************************************
   20 ************************************************************
   10 ************************************************************
     0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6
               0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0
               RSSI(-dBm) per second (last 60 seconds)



      111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  140
  130
  120
  110 ############################################################
  100 ############################################################
   90 ############################################################
   80 ############################################################
   70 ############################################################
   60 ############################################################
   50 ############################################################
   40 ############################################################
   30 ############################################################
   20 ############################################################
   10 ############################################################
     0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6
               0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0
                RSSI(-dBm) per minute (last 60 minutes)
              * = maximum RSSI   # = average RSSI



      111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  140
  130
  120
  110 ########################################################################
  100 ########################################################################
   90 ########################################################################
   80 ########################################################################
   70 ########################################################################
   60 ########################################################################
   50 ########################################################################
   40 ########################################################################
   30 ########################################################################
   20 ########################################################################
   10 ########################################################################
     0....5....1....1....2....2....3....3....4....4....5....5....6....6....7..
               0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0
               RSSI(-dBm) per hour (last 72 hours)
             * = maximum RSSI   # = average RSSI
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It is too broad. Provide more details, such as what you consider optimum. The configuration could help if you are having problems.

Comment: Hi Maupin ,just want to confirm if RSSI vale is optimum here.

Comment: Higher the RSSI is better or lower ?

Comment: The higher the RSSI, the better. You have a good value here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominally, a higher RSSI is better, but understand that RSSI is arbitrarily defined by a particular vendor, and you can't compare it with other models, or, sometimes, with the same model which has a different software version.

You can search the Internet for RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication) to find explanations like [Received signal strength indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication).

Cisco has some documentation on 3G RSSI. You can search for your particular equipment, for example: [Configuring 3G Wireless WAN on Modular and Fixed ISRs (HWIC-3G-GSM, HWIC-3G-HSPA, PCEX-3G-HSPA-x)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/1800/1861/software/feature/guide/mrwlsgsm.html)

> **Note** The RSSI should be better than -90 dBm for steady and reliable
>   connection.